# Why isn't prepare statement executing?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying bind statement to insert data to table. All I know is that connection is established but the prepare statement isn't working. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<?php
class connDb{
    private $link;
private $host;
private $user;
private $pass;
private $dbname;
    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $dbname){
        $this->host=$host;
        $this->user=$user;
        $this->pass=$pass;
        $this->dbname=$dbname;
        $this->link=mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname)
            OR
        die("Not connected to MySQL");
    }
}
?>
<?php
$conn1=new connDb("localhost", "root", "", "dbind");
$xyz=$conn1->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
$x="vikas";
$y="vikas@gmail.com";
$z="123n";
$xyz->bind_param('sss', $x, $y, $z);

$xyz->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Besides answers given so far, check for errors on the query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and error reporting is another useful debugging tool http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Vikas Kumar. How run this code `$xyz=$conn1->getLink()->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
`

Comment: @Vikas Kumar your accepted answer i got error `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in F:\Ampps\www\test\index.php on line 27`.

Comment: @razibalmamun That comment would be better posted on the answer itself so the person can correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the MySQLi connection not your own object.

```
<?php
class connDb{
    private $link;
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $dbname;
    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $dbname){
        $this->host=$host;
        $this->user=$user;
        $this->pass=$pass;
        $this->dbname=$dbname;
        $this->link=mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname)
            OR
        die("Not connected to MySQL");
    }
    public function getLink() {
        return $this->link;
    }
}

$conn1=new connDb("localhost", "root", "", "dbind");
$xyz=$conn1->getLink()->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
$x="vikas";
$y="vikas@gmail.com";
$z="123n";
$xyz->bind_param('sss', $x, $y, $z);

$xyz->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Copying another answer makes yours pretty useless.

Comment: You can check the timestamp. My answer was before your answer got posted. I updated it because its better to use private variables.

Comment: @jeroen actually... this guy's more the one who copied, going from  http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40156111/1 to http://stackoverflow.com/a/40156111/ and no explanation to boot.

Comment: @Fred-ii- True, but this answer was edited within the 5 minutes as well. With what looks like a direct copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks but I had to specify column names either to make it work. Adding column names in query necessary?

Comment: @jeroen Is posting a first WORKING version and updating it to make it better forbidden?

Comment: enough with the (petty) downvote war. If that's all that matters, then play Farmville. Quite childish if you ask me.

Comment: No. If you exactly have 3 columns and you give 3 columns in the statement it should work. Otherwise you need to write them in the statement.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @FabioWidmer Just so you know and you do go off downvoting me.... I didn't downvote, or anyone for that matter. Some go off on a dv spree whenever someone is present and assumes wrongly, keep that in mind.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't downvoted any of your answers or questions.

Comment: @FabioWidmer No problemo... I'm just saying. Sometimes when an answer is downvoted, some assume it's me and goes off on a psycho dv spree *lol* and I've seen it happen before. We're all in this together. If we can provide someone with a solution because someone else did not or left something out, it should be mentioned that they made an error and should be corrected/clarified. TBH, I will only downvote an answer if I feel it's very bad and doesn't answer the question and that happens rarely.

Comment: Check here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php they have used the object. i.e., $mysqli->prepare Is that different from mine?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay. It just sad that someone who has 69k rating needs to downvote my answer just because other people can also answer a question with the same solution... Not talking about you!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong: Your `connDb` class is not a mysqli object, it just contains a private property that is a mysqli object.

You would need a getter to use that.

For example:

```
<?php
class connDb{
    private $link;
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $dbname;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $dbname){
        $this->host=$host;
        $this->user=$user;
        $this->pass=$pass;
        $this->dbname=$dbname;
        $this->link=mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname)
            OR
        die("Not connected to MySQL");
    }

    public function getLink() {
         return $this->link;
    }
}

$conn1=new connDb("localhost", "root", "", "dbind");
$xyz=$conn1->getLink()->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
...
```

Comment: Seems like there's a dv war going on; not very nice on whoever's part. But I do have my doubts.

Comment: Thanks but I had to specify column names either to make it work. Adding column names in query necessary?

Comment: @VikasKumar Only if there are more columns in the table than the 3 you are adding right now in the prepared statement.

Comment: There are 4 columns. One is auto incrementing and is NOT NULL. What you say?

Comment: In this case you need to enter the columns with for example a 0 or you specify the 3 columns.

Comment: @VikasKumar Add column names or use `INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?)`. Assuming that the id is the first...

Comment: or `INSERT INTO table1 (id, col_x, col_y, col_z) VALUES('', ?, ?, ?)`. If their unknown column is AI and accepts NULL, then yeah.. yours would work `(NULL, ?, ?, ?)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You missed return `$this->link;`

Please add new function in `connDb` class

```
public function getDB() {
   return $this->link;
}
```

So, finally follow bellow code :

```
<?php
class connDb{
    private $link;
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $dbname;
    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $dbname){
        $this->host=$host;
        $this->user=$user;
        $this->pass=$pass;
        $this->dbname=$dbname;
        $this->link = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname) OR die("Not connected to MySQL");
    }

    public function getDB() {
        return $this->link;
    }
}
?>

<?php
$conn1=new connDb("localhost", "root", "mysql", "db_mvc");
$xyz=$conn1->getDB()->prepare("INSERT INTO category (name, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
$x="vikas";
$y="vikas@gmail.com";
$z="123n";
$xyz->bind_param('sss', $x, $y, $z);
$xyz->execute();
?>
```

Comment: so you went from http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40156111/1 to that now, I see.

Comment: oh and that dv you got, isn't mine.

Comment: Yes it's working now but I've seen quries without specifying columns also work.

Comment: @VikasKumar please mention you table column name, i will edit my answer.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: srno, name, email, password

Comment: Okay, can you tell why can't I use $conn1->prepare instead? Check it here, they have used it: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php i.e., $mysqli->prepare()

Comment: Thanks for question. Your example code is used no `class` and `method`. but you was used `class` and call `object`